# Simplify Multiple Functions for Similar Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to jQuery, and after looking around in different threads I still can't seem to figure this out. Hoping someone out there is kind enough to break this down for me with kid gloves.

I'm trying to figure out how to simplify multiple functions to achieve different popups for different, but similar elements.

Here's what it currently looks like:

```
$("#cooper_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#cooper_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#cooper_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$("#quentin_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#quentin_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#quentin_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$("#jasper_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#jasper_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#jasper_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$("#jordan_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#jordan_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#jordan_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$("#james_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#james_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#james_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$("#liam_link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#liam_overlay").fadeIn(500);
$("#liam_popup").fadeIn(500,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$('.close').click(function() {
$("#cooper_overlay, #quentin_overlay, #jasper_overlay, #jordan_overlay, #james_overlay, #liam_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$("#cooper_overlay, #quentin_overlay, #jasper_overlay, #jordan_overlay, #james_overlay, #liam_overlay").fadeOut(500);
});

$("#cooper_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#cooper_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$("#quentin_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#quentin_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$("#jasper_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#jasper_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$("#jordan_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#jordan_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$("#james_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#james_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$("#liam_popup").on('blur',function(){
$("#liam_overlay").fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Here's a CodePen for the full thing:

http://codepen.io/chubbaluv/pen/GqZwjE

Comment: This is probably a better topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since you're not asking a question about a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Look again. @devlincarnate. That's a problem to be fixed :-)

Comment: @mmm - then perhaps you should edit the question and clarify the question so the problem is clearer.  Because all I see is a request to simplify code, which is not generally considered to be on topic for SO.

Comment: No, you are basically right @devlincarnate. But the code isn't suitable for code review I'd say...

Comment: @devlincarnate I wasn't aware of Code Review, and this was the only place I knew to turn for help! Thanks for letting me know there's another place to go for help!

Comment: @BrianCortright - no problem.  That's why I didn't downvote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution based on your markup.. of course there are more ways of doing this but not sure how much control u have over the markup

```
$(".rider").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// get the link id
var linkid = this.id
// get the unique part of the section
var id = linkid.replace("_link","");
// since all the elements have this part in their name, use it
$("#"+id+"_overlay").fadeIn(500);
  $("#"+id+"_popup").fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });

});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help!

I have a good amount of control over the markup on this one (which is butchered from trying to get the jQuery to work with multiple different attempts), so I can change the markup to whatever is best.

I'm just a designer who knows enough HTML/CSS to hack apart different CMS', but now am getting tasked with more complex projects at work. This jQuery stuff is very new to me, and I'm trying to wrap my head around. I can't thank you enough for your help!